# Android resource linking failed : 'à¥®dp' is incompatible with attribute layout_marginBottom (attr) dimension

Tags: xml

Android resource linking failed
Output:  C:\Users\backup\AndroidStudioProjects\GEUSPE\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_home.xml:11: error: 'à¥®dp' is incompatible with attribute layout_marginBottom (attr) dimension.
C:\Users\backup\AndroidStudioProjects\GEUSPE\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_home.xml:11: error: 'à¥®dp' is incompatible with attribute layout_marginEnd (attr) dimension.
C:\Users\backup\AndroidStudioProjects\GEUSPE\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_home.xml:11: error: 'à¥®dp' is incompatible with attribute layout_marginLeft (attr) dimension.
C:\Users\backup\AndroidStudioProjects\GEUSPE\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_home.xml:11: error: 'à¥®dp' is incompatible with attribute layout_marginRight (attr) dimension.
C:\Users\backup\AndroidStudioProjects\GEUSPE\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_home.xml:11: error: 'à¥®dp' is incompatible with attribute layout_marginStart (attr) dimension.
C:\Users\backup\AndroidStudioProjects\GEUSPE\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_home.xml:11: error: 'à¥®dp' is incompatible with attribute layout_marginTop (attr) dimension.
C:\Users\backup\AndroidStudioProjects\GEUSPE\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_home.xml:34: error: 'à¥®dp' is incompatible with attribute layout_marginBottom (attr) dimension.
C:\Users\backup\AndroidStudioProjects\GEUSPE\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_home.xml:34: error: 'à¥®dp' is incompatible with attribute layout_marginEnd (attr) dimension.
C:\Users\backup\AndroidStudioProjects\GEUSPE\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_home.xml:34: error: 'à¥®dp' is incompatible with attribute layout_marginLeft (attr) dimension.
C:\Users\backup\AndroidStudioProjects\GEUSPE\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_home.xml:34: error: 'à¥®dp' is incompatible with attribute layout_marginRight (attr) dimension.
C:\Users\backup\AndroidStudioProjects\GEUSPE\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_home.xml:34: error: 'à¥®dp' is incompatible with attribute layout_marginStart (attr) dimension.
C:\Users\backup\AndroidStudioProjects\GEUSPE\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_home.xml:34: error: 'à¥®dp' is incompatible with attribute layout_marginTop (attr) dimension.
C:\Users\backup\AndroidStudioProjects\GEUSPE\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_home.xml:34: error: 'à¥©à¥¦à¥¬dp' is incompatible with attribute layout_width (attr) dimension|enum [fill_parent=4294967295, match_parent=4294967295, wrap_content=4294967294].
C:\Users\backup\AndroidStudioProjects\GEUSPE\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_home.xml:61: error: 'à¥®dp' is incompatible with attribute layout_marginBottom (attr) dimension.
C:\Users\backup\AndroidStudioProjects\GEUSPE\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_home.xml:61: error: 'à¥®dp' is incompatible with attribute layout_marginEnd (attr) dimension.
C:\Users\backup\AndroidStudioProjects\GEUSPE\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_home.xml:61: error: 'à¥®dp' is incompatible with attribute layout_marginLeft (attr) dimension.
C:\Users\backup\AndroidStudioProjects\GEUSPE\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_home.xml:61: error: 'à¥®dp' is incompatible with attribute layout_marginRight (attr) dimension.
C:\Users\backup\AndroidStudioProjects\GEUSPE\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_home.xml:61: error: 'à¥®dp' is incompatible with attribute layout_marginStart (attr) dimension.
C:\Users\backup\AndroidStudioProjects\GEUSPE\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_home.xml:61: error: 'à¥®dp' is incompatible with attribute layout_marginTop (attr) dimension.
C:\Users\backup\AndroidStudioProjects\GEUSPE\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_home.xml:91: error: 'à¥®dp' is incompatible with attribute layout_marginBottom (attr) dimension.

Command: C:\Users\backup.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\7e5a13a6d0fe9b04a8af7fd06640bd69\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\backup\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        C:\Users\backup\AndroidStudioProjects\GEUSPE\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        C:\Users\backup\AndroidStudioProjects\GEUSPE\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @C:\Users\backup\AndroidStudioProjects\GEUSPE\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        C:\Users\backup\AndroidStudioProjects\GEUSPE\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.example.backup.geuspe\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        C:\Users\backup\AndroidStudioProjects\GEUSPE\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

Answer (score 2):

Look at the error:

```
activity_home.xml:61: error: 'à¥®dp' is incompatible with attribute layout_marginLeft (attr) dimension.
```

That means that in your file `activity_home.xml` you're using the attribute `layout_marginLeft` and trying to pass the value `à¥®dp`.  This is not a valid value - either a mistype or something to do with your system's locale. Try using something like `16dp` or similar.

You can find more information about attribute type dimension here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Dimension

Comment: Thanks Izabela Orlowska for your answer.I did not pass ' à¥®dp ' in my code. It is by default coming after creating UI of my activity by using drag n drop.

Comment: Glad it works :) I think it might be related to ANSI vs UTF-8 issues that gradle is replacing currently - https://issuetracker.google.com/116673790